# Q: Sort a List of objects by an inner List with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have an ELementList and each element has an diagrammList with several diagram’s.

I want to select all elements which has a diagram with the searchname into its diagrammList. (this works) But I want also sort these List by the Layername.

Is the a way  to do this?

Thanks

```
namespace ConsoleLinq
{
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.Linq;
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Collection<ElementBase> ELementList = new Collection<ElementBase>();
            ElementBase elementObjekt = new ElementBase { Name = "Node1" };
            elementObjekt.DiagramListe.Add(new Diagram { Name = "Diagram1", LayerName = "Layer2" });
            elementObjekt.DiagramListe.Add(new Diagram { Name = "Diagram2", LayerName = "Layer1" });
            ELementList.Add(elementObjekt);
            elementObjekt = new ElementBase { Name = "Node2" };
            elementObjekt.DiagramListe.Add(new Diagram { Name = "Diagram1", LayerName = "Layer1" });
            ELementList.Add(elementObjekt);
            elementObjekt = new ElementBase { Name = "Node3" };
            elementObjekt.DiagramListe.Add(new Diagram { Name = "Diagram2", LayerName = "Layer1" });
            ELementList.Add(elementObjekt);

            // is there a way to select any item in ELementList which are "Diagram1" and sort the items by LayerName?
            var searchList = (from item in ELementList
                          where item.DiagramListe.GetDiagram("Diagram1") != null
                          select item).ToList();
            // output should
            // searchList[0].Name = "Node2";
            // searchList[1].Name = "Node1";

            foreach (var item in searchList) item.DoSomething();
        }
    }

    public class ElementBase
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public DiagramListe DiagramListe = new DiagramListe();

        public void DoSomething() { }
    }

    public class DiagramListe : Collection<Diagram>
    {
        public Diagram GetDiagram(string diagramName)
            => (from obj in this
                where obj.Name == diagramName
                select obj).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public class Diagram
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LayerName { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you want to sort by `ElementBase.Name` and then by `Diagram.LayerName` or only by `Diagram.LayerName`?

Comment: only by [tag:Diagram.LayerName]

Comment: But both of them have a `Layer1` why do you expect `Node2` be first? Just because it has fewer items?

Comment: Because the `"Diagram1"` in `"Node2"` has `LayerName = "Layer1"` and the `"Diagram1"` in `"Node1"` has `LayerName = "Layer2"`. So sorted by LayerName the expected output makes sense imo (LayerNames of Diagrams we are not searching for are ignored).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `Select` into an anonymous object that also contains the `LayerName` in addition to the `ElementBase`, then use `OrderBy` to sort these anonymous objects by `LayerName`, then `Select` again to get the `ElementBase` back out of the anonymous objects.

```
var diagramNameSearchInput = "Diagram1"
var searchList = 
    (    from item in ELementList
         // put diagram into a variable so we call GetDiagram() only once per element
         let matchingDiagram = item.DiagramListe.GetDiagram(diagramNameSearchInput) 
         where matchingDiagram != null
         select new { // create anonymous object with all properties we need
             BaseItem = item,
             LayerName = matchingDiagram.LayerName
         }
    )
    .OrderBy(a => a.LayerName) // sort anonymous objects
    .Select(a => a.BaseItem)   // result list will contain ElementBase elements
    .ToList();
```

[C# Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/B7xMuM) for this example.